# Check if values are the same for each row over a critiera in another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d65296be8fd56d2ed4e31d940117aff8)**

```
CREATE TABLE campaigns (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    campaign VARCHAR,
    supplier VARCHAR,
    plan_quantity DECIMAL
);

INSERT INTO campaigns
(campaign, supplier, plan_quantity)
VALUES 
('C001', 'supplier_a', '500'),
('C001', 'supplier_a', '500'),
('C001', 'supplier_b', '500'),

('C002', 'supplier_a', '600'),
('C002', 'supplier_b', '700'),

('C003', 'supplier_c', '100'),
('C003', 'supplier_c', '100'),

('C004', 'supplier_a', '900'),
('C004', 'supplier_c', '800'),
('C004', 'supplier_d', '250'),
('C004', 'supplier_d', '250');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
campaign  |   supplier   |   plan_quantity   |     check      |
----------|--------------|-------------------|----------------|-------
  C001    |  supplier_a  |        500        |      same      |
  C001    |  supplier_a  |        500        |      same      |
  C001    |  supplier_b  |        500        |      same      |
----------|--------------|-------------------|----------------|-------
  C002    |  supplier_a  |        600        |    different   |
  C002    |  supplier_b  |        700        |    different   | 
----------|--------------|-------------------|----------------|-------
  C003    |  supplier_c  |        100        |      same      |
  C003    |  supplier_c  |        100        |      same      |
----------|--------------|-------------------|----------------|-------
  C004    |  supplier_a  |        900        |    different   |
  C004    |  supplier_c  |        800        |    different   |
  C004    |  supplier_d  |        250        |    different   |
  C004    |  supplier_d  |        250        |    different   |
```

---

In column `check` in the results I want see if the `plan_quantity` for each `supplier` per `campaign` is the same. 
If yes then it should be written `same` if not it should be written `different`.

```
SELECT
campaign AS campaign,
supplier AS supplier,
plan_quantity AS plan_quantity,
(CASE WHEN plan_quantity for each supplier per campaign is the same THEN 'same' else 'different' END) AS check
FROM campaigns
ORDER BY 1,2,3;
```

I have no clue what function I need to make it work. 
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *window analytic functions* to check the values:

```
select *, 
  case when 
      Min(plan_quantity) over(partition by campaign) 
        = Max(plan_quantity) over(partition by campaign) 
    then 'same' else 'different'
    end as "Check"
from campaigns
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window `max` and `min`

```
SELECT
  campaign AS campaign,
  supplier AS supplier,
  plan_quantity AS plan_quantity,
  CASE WHEN max(plan_quantity) over(partition by supplier, campaign) = min(plan_quantity) over(partition by supplier, campaign) THEN 'same' ELSE 'different' END AS check
FROM campaigns
ORDER BY 1,2,3;
```

Comment: It puts "same" in every row.

Comment: Your wording is ambigious. Try drop `supplier,` from the `partition` clause

Answer (score 0):

You can find out which `campaign` has an unique `plan_quantity` by grouping by `campaign` and simply count distint `plan_quantity`

```sql
SELECT
    campaign AS campaign
FROM campaigns
GROUP BY campaign
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT plan_quantity) = 1
```

And with that you can do what you want. With a join for exemple :

```sql
SELECT
    campaigns.campaign,
    supplier,
    plan_quantity,
    CASE WHEN grouping IS NOT NULL THEN 'same' ELSE 'different' END as check
FROM campaigns
    LEFT JOIN (
        -- Get all campaign with same plan_quantity
        SELECT
            campaign
        FROM campaigns
        GROUP BY campaign
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT plan_quantity) = 1
    ) as grouping
ON campaigns.campaign = grouping.campaign
```