# Check if values are the same for each row over criteria in different other columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5882fdec6b5ec848d0a695470def3bb6)

```
CREATE TABLE campaigns 
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    campaign VARCHAR,
    supplier VARCHAR,
    plan_quantity DECIMAL
);

INSERT INTO campaigns (campaign, supplier, plan_quantity)
VALUES ('C001', 'supplier_a', '500'),
       ('C001', 'supplier_a', '500'),
       ('C001', 'supplier_b', '500'),

       ('C002', 'supplier_a', '600'),
       ('C002', 'supplier_b', '700'),
    
       ('C003', 'supplier_c', '100'),
       ('C003', 'supplier_c', '100'),
  
       ('C004', 'supplier_a', '900'),
       ('C004', 'supplier_c', '800'),
       ('C004', 'supplier_d', '250'),
       ('C004', 'supplier_d', '250'),

       ('C005', 'supplier_b', '380'),
       ('C005', 'supplier_b', '270'),
       ('C005', 'supplier_d', '590');
```

Expected result:

```
campaign  |   supplier   |   plan_quantity   |      check         |
----------|--------------|-------------------|--------------------|-------
  C001    |  supplier_a  |        500        |       same         |
  C001    |  supplier_a  |        500        |       same         |
  C001    |  supplier_b  |        500        |    non-relevant    |
----------|--------------|-------------------|--------------------|-------
  C002    |  supplier_a  |        600        |    non-relevant    |
  C002    |  supplier_b  |        700        |    non-relevant    | 
----------|--------------|-------------------|--------------------|-------
  C003    |  supplier_c  |        100        |       same         |
  C003    |  supplier_c  |        100        |       same         |
----------|--------------|-------------------|--------------------|-------
  C004    |  supplier_a  |        900        |    non-relevant    |
  C004    |  supplier_c  |        800        |    non-relevant    |
  C004    |  supplier_d  |        250        |       same         |
  C004    |  supplier_d  |        250        |       same         |
----------|--------------|-------------------|--------------------|-------
  C005    |  supplier_b  |        380        |     different      |
  C005    |  supplier_b  |        270        |     different      |
  C005    |  supplier_d  |        590        |    non-relevant    |
```

In case a supplier appears multiple times per campaign, I want to see in column `check` if the `plan_quantity` for this supplier is the same in every row.

I am getting close to the result when I modify the query from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70530527/check-if-values-are-the-same-for-each-row-over-a-critiera-in-another-column):

```
SELECT
    campaign AS campaign,
    supplier AS supplier,
    plan_quantity AS plan_quantity,
    (CASE 
         WHEN MIN(plan_quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY supplier, campaign) = MAX(plan_quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY supplier, campaign) 
             THEN 'same' 
             ELSE 'different' 
     END) AS check
 FROM
     campaigns
 ORDER BY 
     1, 2, 3;
```

However, I have no clue how I can add the description non-relevant to the query in case a supplier does not appear multiple times per campaign.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slightly modify the query with an additional *case expression* for when the check is the *same* and indicate any with a count of 1 are non-relevant:

```
select 
  campaign,
  supplier,
  plan_quantity, 
  case when 
      Min(plan_quantity) over(partition by campaign, supplier) 
        = Max(plan_quantity) over(partition by campaign, supplier) 
    then 
        case when Count(*) over(partition by campaign, supplier) = 1 
         then 'non-relevant' else 'same' 
        end
    else 'different'
    end as Check
from campaigns
order by 1,2,3;
```

Comment: Just for my documentation: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d952af8078698d716ca48662aa31c2af

Answer (score 0):

Try to work out a solution according to our natural of thinking. To get this done, we just need to add a check column when its value is non-relevant to the ordered records in column 2, column 3 and column 4. First, group records by column 2 and column 3. If a group has more than one records, change the value of check column to different and group records in this group by column 4. Then, if a subgroup has more than one records, change the value of check column to same. It is roundabout to code the process in SQL. In similar cases, we need a multilevel case statement to work with multiple window functions. The final SQL statement is difficult to understand. The usual way is to fetch the original data out of the database and process it in Python or SPL. SPL, the open-source Java package, is easier to be integrated into a Java program and generate more concise code. It finishes the task with only two lines of code:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | =PG.query("SELECT *,'non-relevant'as check FROM CAMPAIGNS ORDER BY 2,3,4") |
| 2 | >A1.group@o(#2,#3).(if(~.len()>1,~.run(check="different"),~).group@o(#4).(if(~.len()>1,~.run(check="same")))) |